# Zoom on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: zoom-meeting

I installed Zoom on Ubuntu 17.10 (64bit version). The installation seemed successful. However, every time I launch the program:

1. My internet browser (Chrome or Firefox) stop working (pages are not loading)
2. My computer becomes slow at responding
3. I quit Zoom, but the problem persists
4. Eventually, my computer completely freezes. And I need to force the restart.

Moreover, Zoom actually freezes itself as soon as I start interacting with it (start a meeting).
I re-installed the program using different methods (from the Software center and from the terminal), tried to install dependencies, ran `touch ~/.config/zoomus.conf` Nothing helped.

I reached out to Zoom, but they told me it will take them at least a week to get back to me (customer support was very responsive, but the engineers will take their time to analyze the log files).
I can provide more information if necessary.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't wait for Zoom's engineers to get back to you?  Many of us here are *not* developers, and debugging issues such as this one are probably best left to the engineers of the application that is the culprit of the problems.

Comment: Actually, I need to use Zoom as soon as tonight for my grad school classes. And I have two more classes this week. So in reality I'm in a bad situation and can't wait a week.

Comment: The problem was with NVIDIA drivers. I had to update them manually, and then Zoom worked just fine.